# Laravel: Can't access Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I've made Post and User models and defined a one to many relationship between the two like so:

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'profile_picture',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    public function posts () {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class,'post_author');
    }
}
```

**Post.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'post_title', 'post_content', 'post_author', 'post_type', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
    ];
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'id');
    }
    public function postfields() {
        return $this->hasMany(PostField::class);
    }
}
```

Now, in my blog controller I compact the Post class into my blog view like so:

**BlogController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Post;

use App\User;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Post $post) {
        $blog_posts = Post::with('user')->where('post_type', '=', 'blog')->get();
        return view('blog', compact('blog_posts'));
    }
}
```

Now I attempt to access the relationship inside of the blog view:

```
@foreach ($blog_posts as $blog_post)
    <div class="post item">
        {{ $blog_post->post_title }}
        {{ $blog_post->post_content }}
        {{ $blog_post->user->name }}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Everything appears as it should in the blog view when there is only one blog post in the database, however I get the following error when there is more than one:

ErrorException in 84794846d554b14eb937f08dfef09b6f1edd91c6.php line 43:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\MAMP\htdocs\Biota-New\resources\views\blog.blade.php)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's a DD of the $blog_posts variable:

```
Collection {#198 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Post {#194 ▼
      #fillable: array:6 [▼
        0 => "post_title"
        1 => "post_content"
        2 => "post_author"
        3 => "post_type"
        4 => "created_at"
        5 => "updated_at"
      ]
      #connection: null
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:7 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "post_title" => "TEST"
        "post_content" => "Test post"
        "post_author" => 1
        "post_type" => "blog"
        "created_at" => "2016-10-08 14:20:07"
        "updated_at" => "2016-10-08 14:20:07"
      ]
      #original: array:7 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "post_title" => "TEST"
        "post_content" => "Test post"
        "post_author" => 1
        "post_type" => "blog"
        "created_at" => "2016-10-08 14:20:07"
        "updated_at" => "2016-10-08 14:20:07"
      ]
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "user" => User {#199 ▼
          #fillable: array:4 [▼
            0 => "name"
            1 => "email"
            2 => "password"
            3 => "profile_picture"
          ]
          #hidden: array:2 [▼
            0 => "password"
            1 => "remember_token"
          ]
          #connection: null
          #table: null
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          #perPage: 15
          +incrementing: true
          +timestamps: true
          #attributes: array:9 [▼
            "id" => 1
            "name" => "Sup3rL3on"
            "email" => "codeoncaffeine1@gmail.com"
            "password" => "$2y$10$b6pMtiKt0LcDCeRtTlVJzOL3BvD6Ru1TihbOhM7FOHUscW0daIwGC"
            "profile_picture" => "default-profile-picture"
            "account_type" => 1
            "remember_token" => null
            "created_at" => null
            "updated_at" => null
          ]
          #original: array:9 [▼
            "id" => 1
            "name" => "Sup3rL3on"
            "email" => "codeoncaffeine1@gmail.com"
            "password" => "$2y$10$b6pMtiKt0LcDCeRtTlVJzOL3BvD6Ru1TihbOhM7FOHUscW0daIwGC"
            "profile_picture" => "default-profile-picture"
            "account_type" => 1
            "remember_token" => null
            "created_at" => null
            "updated_at" => null
          ]
          #relations: []
          #visible: []
          #appends: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▼
            0 => "*"
          ]
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #casts: []
          #touches: []
          #observables: []
          #with: []
          #morphClass: null
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        }
      ]
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▼
        0 => "*"
      ]
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
    1 => Post {#195 ▼
      #fillable: array:6 [▼
        0 => "post_title"
        1 => "post_content"
        2 => "post_author"
        3 => "post_type"
        4 => "created_at"
        5 => "updated_at"
      ]
      #connection: null
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:7 [▼
        "id" => 6
        "post_title" => "TEST"
        "post_content" => "Test post"
        "post_author" => 1
        "post_type" => "blog"
        "created_at" => "2016-10-08 14:20:07"
        "updated_at" => "2016-10-08 14:20:07"
      ]
      #original: array:7 [▼
        "id" => 6
        "post_title" => "TEST"
        "post_content" => "Test post"
        "post_author" => 1
        "post_type" => "blog"
        "created_at" => "2016-10-08 14:20:07"
        "updated_at" => "2016-10-08 14:20:07"
      ]
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "user" => null
      ]
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▼
        0 => "*"
      ]
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
  ]
}
```

**Blog.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.front-header')

@section('content')
<style>
    .hero-image {
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url(images/hero-2.jpg);
    }
</style>


<div class="hero-image hero-image-inner-page">
    <div class="hero-image-inner">
        <div class="text">
            <h1>Blog</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<main>
    <section class="blog">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="posts">
        <div class="items">
            <!-- 
            <div class="post item">
                <h3 data-field="post_title"></h3>
                <p data-field="post_content"></p>
                <img src="http://fiddle-earth.com/updates/madsa/img/image00.png" alt="">
                <div class="post-data">
                    <img data-field="author_profile_picture" alt="">
                    <p>posted by <strong data-field="post_author"></strong> on <span data-field="post_date"></span></p>
                </div>
            </div> -->


            @foreach ($blog_posts as $blog_post)
                <div class="post item">
                    <h3 data-field="post_title">{{ $blog_post->post_title }}</h3>
                    <p data-field="post_content">{{ $blog_post->post_content }}</p>
                    <!-- <img src="http://fiddle-earth.com/updates/madsa/img/image00.png" alt=""> -->
                    <div class="post-data">
                        <img data-field="author_profile_picture" alt="">
                        @if($blog_post->user()!=null)
                            {{ $blog_post->user->name }}
                        @endif
                        <p>posted by <strong data-field="post_author"></strong> on <span data-field="post_date"></span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach

        </div>
        <!-- <a href="#" class="items-load">Load more</a> -->
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>




<script src="assets/js/loadmore.js"></script>
<script>
$('.posts').loadmore({
    source: 'assets/js/json/blog-json.php',
    img: 'uploads/',
    step: 4
});
</script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, the `User` relation in the Post model is causing the exception. So, when you call:

```
{{ $blog_post->user->name }}
```

it can't  find the user associated with that post. I am guessing that the foreign key for `User` table is not the same as [guessed](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) by Laravel:

> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with _id. However, if the foreign key on the Comment model is not post_id, you may pass a custom key name as the second argument to the belongsTo method:

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'foreign_key');
}
```

So in your case, it would be something like this:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'post_user_id'); //Replace post_user_id with the id convention you are using.
}
```

<s>**Update:**</s>

<s>Thanks for the dd on your $blog_posts. I can see that the user is being fetched but it's not being called correctly. It's a function so you need to treat it as a function. Modify your blade file to retrieve the user like this:</s>

```
{{ $blog_post->user()->name }}
```

This should get the valid user collection.

<s>**Update 2:**</s>

As I can see from the dump, the user relation from the second `Post` is null. Make sure it's not null when you are creating the post and to deal with it in the blade, wrap it in a null check:

```
@foreach ($blog_posts as $blog_post)
<div class="post item">
    {{ $blog_post->post_title }}
    {{ $blog_post->post_content }}
    @if($blog_post->user()!=null)
        {{ $blog_post->user()->name }}
    @endif
</div>
@endforeach
```

**Update 3:**

It actually is supposed to be called as an attribute rather than a function since it returns 'BelongsTo' when called as a function. Try the following now:

```
@foreach ($blog_posts as $blog_post)
<div class="post item">
    {{ $blog_post->post_title }}
    {{ $blog_post->post_content }}
    @if($blog_post->user!=null)
        {{ $blog_post->user->name }}
    @endif
</div>
@endforeach
```

I've reproduced the same issue here and this fixes it. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hey, I've just updated the question so that the foreign key parameter is included, unfortunately I get a different error. Thanks for the answer. Do you have any thoughts on the new error>

Comment: Can you please **dd** the **$blog_posts** in your BlogsController and paste the output here so I can actually see what's going on. dd($blog_posts);

Comment: Just added it to the question, hope it helps.

Comment: @6rs_Leon Can you please expand the first Post and then expand the `Original` anchor and all of subtrees on it. Also expand the `Relations` anchor and all of it's subtrees. The goal is to see what the `user` is.

Comment: The full structure is now added to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I now get the following: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name (View: C:\MAMP\htdocs\Biota-New\resources\views\blog.blade.php)

Comment: Please check the update 2. I've added the null check to make sure the User relation is not null.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried adding the check from update 2, however I still get exactly the same error.

Comment: Weird. Let me reproduce this and I'll post the solution afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it. Let me know if there's anything I can do to help.

Comment: I now get Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\MAMP\htdocs\Biota-New\resources\views\blog.blade.php)

Comment: Trying to figure out what the difference between my setup and your setup is.

Comment: Post your blade file here. I believe, it's not in sync with mine.

Comment: Just posted the blade file to the question.

Comment: Remove () from this line: `@if($blog_post->user()!=null)` so it become `@if($blog_post->user!=null)`

Comment: Excellent, now I haven't got an error. Only the name from the first relationship is shown though.

Comment: Yes, that's because the user is null for second post. i.e: There's no user with the id `6`. Create a user with id 6 and you will have it displayed. Basically, for every post id there has to be a corresponding user id.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! It's now working as it should be.

Comment: Great and no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

I found no error try

`composer dump-autoload`

`php artisan view:clear`

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

instead of

```
@foreach ($blog_posts as $blog_post)
    <div class="post item">
        {{ $blog_post->post_title }}
        {{ $blog_post->post_content }}
        {{ $blog_post->user->name }}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Use the following:

```
    @foreach ($blog_posts as $blog_post)
            <div class="post item">
                {{ $blog_post->post_title }}
                {{ $blog_post->post_content }}
                @foreach($blog_post->user as $user)
                    {{ $user->name }}
                @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

Comment: It returns the following error: Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\MAMP\htdocs\Biota-New\resources\views\blog.blade.php)

Comment: Try renaming the function to users() and try out users in your blade views ofcourse to see if it makes any difference. Try to restart your server too.

Comment: I saw your answer in the other question, thats because the second DD(blog_posts) gives you back:  #relations: array:1 [▼
        "user" => null
      ]

so that user = null that means that what you get back is what you're suppposed to get back!